# análisis sintáctico con expresión regular

Tags: regex

Deseo analizar una sentencia mediante una expresión regular. La sentencia sería del tipo:
`function_0("param1", 9, funcn_2("5", func_3("param5", "param6"), "param"), "param2")`
Pero no soy capaz de separar los parámetros ni de establecer dónde empieza y donde acaba cada función interna.
La expresión que utilizo para separar los parámetros separados por comas es:
`'/(?:^|,\s*)(?=[^"]|(")?)"?((?(1)[^"]*|[^,"]*))"?(?=,|$)/m'`